# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application (with Maven)

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I get the error `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application` in IDEA when I try to compile JavaFX application.
I added the modules via maven. There is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>clockAlarm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Program</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How it can be fixed if I want to use JavaFX modules only via maven with no downloading sdk and setup it by myself?

There is Programm class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Program extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Text text = new Text("Alarm Clock");
        text.setLayoutY(80);
        text.setLayoutX(100);

        Group group = new Group(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("alarmClock");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(250);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

All project settings are set to 13 java version.

Comment: Try adding https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx as a maven dependency

Comment: As I understand this can be fixed only with https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#run way. All ways with maven didn't work for me

Comment: You are missing all the JavaFX dependencies in your pom. See for reference this [pom](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/Maven/hellofx/pom.xml)